# RuntimeError: Model class snippets.models.Snippet doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-apps

when I run Django use `restful_framework`. I met an error:

```
RuntimeError: Model class snippets.models.Snippet doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS
```

who can help me. Thanks every one who can help me.
my serializers.py code:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from snippets.models import Product
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('id', 'created', 'name', 'describe', 'price', 'isDelete')
```

Comment: If the problem resolved, would you kindly set it to answer?

Comment: thank you.  I find  i import modules error. this snippets module should be changed api.then success run

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should add `snippets` app into `INSTALLED_APPS`, then you can use your model which is defined in your app.

Are you creating the `snippets` app using the 'python manage.py' command or you are creating it by yourself? The error might happen when your app doesn't create properly and you forgot to make `package` for it.

Comment: thank you. very much. import modules error. this quesition  resolved.